# $summernote is not defined HTMLTextAreaElement.onImageUpload

Tags: jquery, ajax, summernote

I am using Summernote and it works for all text but I am having issues seting up the AJAX call to upload the image. **I am receiving warning "$summernote is not defined ReferenceError: $summernote is not defined
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.onImageUpload".** It is not an actual error, just a warning but the function is not called.

```js
      <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#summernote').summernote({
           lang: 'en-EN',
           placeholder: 'Article content...',
           tabsize: 2,
           height: 200,
           shortCuts: false,
           disableDragAndDrop: true,
           toolbar: [
             ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
             ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
             ['color', ['color']], 
             ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
             ['table', ['table']],
             ['insert', ['link', 'picture']],
             ['view', ['codeview', 'help']]
           ],
           callbacks: {
       onImageUpload: function(files) {
         // upload image to server and create imgNode...
         $summernote.summernote('insertNode', imgNode);
       }
     }
         });
     });

     $('#summernote').on('summernote.image.upload', function(we, files) {
    // upload image to server and create imgNode...
    $summernote.summernote('insertNode', imgNode);
  });
      </script>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.16/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.16/dist/summernote.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body>

<form ...>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <textarea id="summernote" name="editordata"><?php echo $this->input->post('editordata'); ?></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where exactly is that variable defined?  You say it is only a warning, but you also say that your method is not called.  That's not a warning.  That's a broken null pointer exception due to an undefined variable.

Comment: I am following the instructions on Summernote's website (summernote.org/getting-started), I assume the variable is in the included Summernote js. This was my first thought as well, I will check the js file.

Comment: I don't see any reference to a `$summernote` variable in that document page

Comment: Use this link (summernote.org/deep-dive/) and search for callback onImageUpload.

Comment: That documentation looks incomplete.  It also doesn't show where that variable comes from.  Any case, try this.  `var $summernote = $('#summernote').summernote({`  Store the response from the `summernote()` method in that variable.  That's what I would have expected that documentation to have shown at some point.

Comment: Thanks Taplar, the issue was due to a bar URL in the AJAX call, the file upload AJAX script had an error..

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, there was an error in the AJAX call.